# Filtering date ranges into continuous ranges without overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have ranges representing days, weeks, months, quarters and years. I want to get non overlapping ranges out of this that cover the most amount of total period, while also using smallest ranges possible.

For example I might have all four weeks for january, the months february and march, and quarters 2,3,4 that add up to a year and that would be fine. But If I was missing monthly data for february I would have to use 1st quarter, and If that too was missing then the year data.

Example Input

```
PeriodName  StartDate   EndDate
Jan 05  2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 2005-01-31 00:00:00.000
Q1 05   2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 2005-03-31 00:00:00.000
Yr 2005 2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 2005-12-31 00:00:00.000
Feb 05  2005-02-01 00:00:00.000 2005-02-28 00:00:00.000
Mar 05  2005-03-01 00:00:00.000 2005-03-31 00:00:00.000
Apr 05  2005-04-01 00:00:00.000 2005-04-30 00:00:00.000
Q2 05   2005-04-01 00:00:00.000 2005-06-30 00:00:00.000
May 05  2005-05-01 00:00:00.000 2005-05-31 00:00:00.000
Jul 05  2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 2005-07-31 00:00:00.000
Q3 05   2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 2005-09-30 00:00:00.000
Q4 05   2005-10-01 00:00:00.000 2005-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Output:

```
PeriodName  StartDate   EndDate
Jan 05  2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 2005-01-31 00:00:00.000
Feb 05  2005-02-01 00:00:00.000 2005-02-28 00:00:00.000
Mar 05  2005-03-01 00:00:00.000 2005-03-31 00:00:00.000
Q2 05   2005-04-01 00:00:00.000 2005-06-30 00:00:00.000
Q3 05   2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 2005-09-30 00:00:00.000
Q4 05   2005-10-01 00:00:00.000 2005-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Can your provide examples along with your expected output

Comment: Added the example

Comment: I see, in your output example you're showing `Q2 05` because you're missing data for `Jun 05`, right?

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: So in other words, when gaps in a series of month ranges are encountered, these cause the range to escalate, first into quarter ranges, and then if there are gaps in the quarter ranges, escalate into full-year ranges. Or viewed another way, if the highest-level ranges are sequential, then see if each individual range can be broken down into a contiguous series of lower ranges, and recurse until the lowest range possible is reached.

Comment: Shouldn't the `EndDate` be 23:59:59.997 otherwise you're missing the last day of each period.

Are you storing `DatePeriod` as a string in the table and not displaying for our purposes as eg `SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE())`

Comment: Steve the problem is I don't know how to do that declaratively. @Cool_Br33ze only the date portions are used for calculations

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on (2005/12/14/etc.)?

Comment: @tarheel I'm on 2016

Comment: The first thing you want to do is to change your `DateTime` columns to `Date`.

Comment: I do not think that you can get correct answer from your provided samples. You have to show how week ranges are kept in the table. Especially weeks that belong to 2 different months. And can your building range be more than 1 year?

Answer (score 0):

@IvanAnatolievich, it's certainly a little bit tricky.

I'm not at my desktop computer to test this, but I'd approach it something like this:

```
WITH step1 AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) AS days_in_period
    FROM [YOUR_SOURCE_TABLE]
)
,step2 AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN days_in_period BETWEEN 365 AND 366 THEN 
                'Y'
            WHEN days_in_period BETWEEN 90 AND 92 THEN 
                'Q'
            WHEN days_in_period BETWEEN 28 AND 31 THEN 
                'M'
            ELSE 
                'X' --this should indicate something wrong
            END AS period_type      
    FROM step1
)
,step3 AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN period_type IN ('Y') THEN 
                DATEPART(YEAR, StartDate) 
            ELSE 
                NULL 
            END AS yr
        ,CASE 
            WHEN period_type IN ('Y', 'Q') THEN 
                DATEPART(QUARTER, StartDate) 
            ELSE 
                NULL 
            END AS qtr
        ,CASE 
            WHEN period_type IN ('Y', 'Q', 'M') THEN    
                DATEPART(MONTH, StartDate)
            ELSE 
                NULL 
            END AS mth
    FROM step2
)
,step4 AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,IIF(period_type = 'Y', COUNT(qtr) OVER (PARTITION BY yr), NULL) AS qtrs_in_yr
        ,IIF(period_type = 'Q', COUNT(mth) OVER (PARTITION BY yr, qtr), NULL) AS mths_in_qtr
    FROM step3
)

SELECT
    COALESCE(mths.period_type, qtrs.period_type, yrs.period_type) AS period_type
    ,COALESCE(mths.PeriodName, qtrs.PeriodName, yrs.PeriodName) AS PeriodName
    ,COALESCE(mths.StartDate, qtrs.StartDate, yrs.StartDate) AS StartDate
    ,COALESCE(mths.EndDate, qtrs.EndDate, yrs.EndDate) AS EndDate

FROM
    (SELECT * FROM step4 WHERE period_type = 'Y') AS yrs

LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM step4 WHERE period_type = 'Q') AS qtrs
    ON (qtrs.yr = yrs.yr)
    AND (yrs.qtrs_in_yr = 4)

LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM step4 WHERE period_type = 'M') AS mths
    AND (mths.yr = yrs.yr)
    AND (mths.qtr = qtrs.qtr)
    AND (qtrs.mths_in_qtr = 3)
```

I'm assuming every lower range is covered by a higher range in your source table. In other words, that there is a full-year entry for all years, and maybe some individual quarters for each year, and maybe some individual months for each quarter.

The first three steps are just ceremony to establish robustly what kind of period we're dealing with and extract some parameters, but what I'm doing in `step_4` is counting how many subranges each higher range has. We don't need to count for the month ranges, because these are not further subdivided.

In `step_5`, I'm starting with a table consisting of just the full-year rows. Then I'm conditionally joining on the quarters for this year, *if* the year consists of 4 quarters.

If there are no quarters, or fewer than 4, then it will simply leave the year row in place as a single row. If there are 4 quarters, then the year row will be expanded out into 4 quarterly rows. I follow the same logic again for each quarter in relation to the months. This leaves us with 3 groups of identical columns.

Finally, in the select, I move right-to-left to condense these three column-groups back into one, which should leave us with the desired results.

Let me know if there's any problem.

Answer (score 0):

My script only work for monthly,quarterly and yearly.

Script can be written neatly and can be optimize after "Require output is clear".
Please throw your real table structure and data.

Sample data,

```
create table #maintable(PeriodName varchar(20)
,StartDate datetime,EndDate datetime)

insert into #maintable VALUES
('Jan 05'  ,'2005-01-01 00:00:00.000','2005-01-31 00:00:00.000')
,('Q1 05 '  ,'2005-01-01 00:00:00.000','2005-03-31 00:00:00.000')
,('Yr 2005' ,'2005-01-01 00:00:00.000','2005-12-31 00:00:00.000')
,('Feb 05'  ,'2005-02-01 00:00:00.000','2005-02-28 00:00:00.000')
,('Mar 05'  ,'2005-03-01 00:00:00.000','2005-03-31 00:00:00.000')
,('Apr 05'  ,'2005-04-01 00:00:00.000','2005-04-30 00:00:00.000')
,('Q2 05'   ,'2005-04-01 00:00:00.000','2005-06-30 00:00:00.000')
,('May 05'  ,'2005-05-01 00:00:00.000','2005-05-31 00:00:00.000')
,('Jul 05'  ,'2005-07-01 00:00:00.000','2005-07-31 00:00:00.000')
,('Q3 05'   ,'2005-07-01 00:00:00.000','2005-09-30 00:00:00.000')
,('Q4 05'   ,'2005-10-01 00:00:00.000','2005-12-31 00:00:00.000')
```

Condition,

```
DECLARE @StartDate date='2005-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate date='2005-12-31'


;with CTE as
(
select PeriodName ,StartDate ,EndDate 
,case when DATEDIFF(month,startdate,enddate)=0 then 
case when month(startdate) in (1,2,3) then 'Q1 ' +cast(right(year(@StartDate),2) as char(2))
when month(startdate) in (4,5,6) then 'Q2 ' +cast(right(year(@StartDate),2) as char(2))
when month(startdate) in (7,8,9) then 'Q3 ' +cast(right(year(@StartDate),2) as char(2))
when month(startdate) in (10,11,12) then 'Q4 ' +cast(right(year(@StartDate),2) as char(2))
END
when DATEDIFF(month,startdate,enddate)=2 
then
case when month(startdate)=1
then 'Q1 '+cast(right(year(@StartDate),2) as char(2))
when month(startdate)=4
then 'Q2 '+cast(right(year(@StartDate),2) as char(2))
when month(startdate)=7
then 'Q3 '+cast(right(year(@StartDate),2) as char(2))
when month(startdate)=10
then 'Q4 '+cast(right(year(@StartDate),2) as char(2))
END
when DATEDIFF(month,startdate,enddate)=11 
then 'Yr '+ cast(year(@StartDate) as char(4))
END MonthGroup
,case when DATEDIFF(month,startdate,enddate)=2 
then
'Q'
when DATEDIFF(month,startdate,enddate)=11 
then 'Yr ' + cast(year(@StartDate) as char(4))
END QuarterGroup
,case when DATEDIFF(month,startdate,enddate)=11 
then
'Yr ' + cast(year(@StartDate) as char(4))

END YrGroup
from #maintable
where StartDate>=@StartDate and EndDate<=@EndDate
--and PeriodName not in('Feb 05','Q2 05')
)
,GroupCTE AS
(
select MonthGroup,count(*) cnt
from CTE C
group by MonthGroup
having count(*)=4
)
,QuarterCTE AS
(
select QuarterGroup,count(*) Qcnt
from CTE C
where QuarterGroup is not null
group by QuarterGroup
--having count(*)=4
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer was built to only work for Month/Quarter/Year time grains, because that was the scope of the sample data provided. This could easily be modified to include Day/Week considerations as well.

**Sample Data:**

Including the `create`/`insert` logic for the sample data provided in the question.

```
create table #sample_data
    (
        PeriodName varchar(10)
        , StartDate datetime
        , EndDate datetime
    )

insert into #sample_data
values ('Jan 05', '2005-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-01-31 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Q1 05', '2005-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-03-31 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Yr 2005', '2005-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-12-31 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Feb 05', '2005-02-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-02-28 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Mar 05', '2005-03-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-03-31 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Apr 05', '2005-04-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-04-30 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Q2 05', '2005-04-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-06-30 00:00:00.000')
    , ('May 05', '2005-05-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-05-31 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Jul 05', '2005-07-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-07-31 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Q3 05', '2005-07-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-09-30 00:00:00.000')
    , ('Q4 05', '2005-10-01 00:00:00.000', '2005-12-31 00:00:00.000')
```

**Answer:**

One assumption being made in the query below is this:

- If there is a `PeriodName` at level `n`, regardless of use in expected output, there is a encapsulating `PeriodName` at level `n+1` where level `n` < `k` and `k` is the maximum level.

Examples of the assumption above are as follows:

- Because `Jan 05` exists, there will be a corresponding `Q1 05` record.
- Because `Jul 05` exists, there will be a corresponding `Q3 05` record.
- Because `Yr 2005` exists at the highest level, there is no encapsulating `PeriodName`.

The query, with comment explanations is below.

```
; with base as
    (
        --Calculate a couple column values for use in later steps
        select sd.PeriodName
        , sd.StartDate
        , sd.EndDate
        , datediff(d, sd.StartDate, sd.EndDate) + 1 as DayCnt
        , case when datediff(d, sd.StartDate, sd.EndDate) + 1 between 28 and 31 then 1 --month record
               when left(sd.PeriodName, 1) = 'Q' then 2 --quarter record
               when left(sd.PeriodName, 1) = 'Y' then 3 --annual record
          end as PrefOrd
        from #sample_data as sd 
    )
    , check_upward as
    (
        --Determine which level n records, account for the duration of PeriodName at level n + 1 
        select a.PeriodName
        , a.StartDate
        , a.EndDate
        , a.PrefOrd
        , a.DayCnt
        , case when b.DayCnt is null then 1 --highest possible level
                when b.DayCnt = sum(a.DayCnt) over (partition by b.PeriodName) then 1
                else 0
            end as EligibleRecFlag
        from base as a
        left join base as b on a.PrefOrd + 1 = b.PrefOrd
                            and a.StartDate >= b.StartDate
                            and a.EndDate <= b.EndDate  
    )
    , check_downard as
    (
        --Determine if there are eligible records that 
        select distinct a.PeriodName, case when sum(b.DayCnt) over (partition by a.PeriodName) >= a.DayCnt then 0 else 1 end as EligibleRecFlag
        from check_upward as a
        inner join check_upward as b on a.PrefOrd > b.PrefOrd
                                 and a.StartDate <= b.StartDate
                                 and a.EndDate >= b.EndDate
        where a.EligibleRecFlag = 1
        and b.EligibleRecFlag = 1   
    )
--Final Select statement
select a.PeriodName
, a.StartDate
, a.EndDate
from check_upward as a
left join check_downard as b on a.PeriodName = b.PeriodName
                            and b.EligibleRecFlag = 0
where b.PeriodName is NULL
and a.EligibleRecFlag = 1
order by 2, 3
```

**Output:**

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| PeriodName |        StartDate        |         EndDate         |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Jan 05     | 2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2005-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| Feb 05     | 2005-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2005-02-28 00:00:00.000 |
| Mar 05     | 2005-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2005-03-31 00:00:00.000 |
| Q2 05      | 2005-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2005-06-30 00:00:00.000 |
| Q3 05      | 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2005-09-30 00:00:00.000 |
| Q4 05      | 2005-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2005-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```